# How to fix 'OverSampling' error in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to build a multi-class multi-label model to classify movie genres based on plots. There are 24 different movie genres, this is the number of movies by genre:

```
    genre   number_of_movies

    Drama       3965
    Comedy      3046
    Thriller    2024
    Romance     1892
    Crime       1447
    Action      1303
    Adventure   1024
    Horror      954
    Mystery     759
    Sci-Fi      723
    Fantasy     707
    Family      682
    Documentary 419
    Biography   373
    War         348
    Music       341
    History     273
    Musical     271
    Sport       261
    Animation   260
    Western     237
    Film-Noir   168
    Short       92
    News        7
```

I'm creating the features using CountVectorizer() as described below:

```
vect = CountVectorizer(max_features=4412, stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1, 3), binary=True)
X = vect.fit_transform(df['plot'])
X.shape
```

**Output:**

```
(7895, 4412)
```

and MultiLabelBinarizer() for creating y_genres:

```
le = MultiLabelBinarizer()
y_genres = le.fit_transform(dataTraining['genres'])
y_genres.shape
```

**Output:**

```
(7895, 24)
```

The objective is to resample all classes but the majority class, using RandomOverSampler and SMOTE from imblearn.over_sampling. Nevertheless, when using:

- RandomOverSampler: It's deleting 2 classes, from 24 to 22.

```
ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=42)
    X_resampled, Y_resampled = ros.fit_sample(X, y_genres)

Y_resampled.shape
```

**Output:**

```
(52690, 22)
```

- SMOTE: is showing me the following error

```
sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
    X_resampled, Y_resampled = sm.fit_sample(X, y_genres)
```

**Error:**

```
Expected n_neighbors <= n_samples,  but n_samples = 2, n_neighbors = 6
```

What should I do to fix the 2 problems described before?

Answer (score 0):

sm.fit_resample might be of rescue.